# More efficient ways to save large object graph and append to it in python

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, pickle

I am crawling pubmeds database of research papers and am running into a problem as my number of nodes is getting too large. Here is how my data structure works:

```
class Network(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__authors = {} #each key is a name and each value is an object
        self.__papers = {} #each key is a pubmed ID and each value is an object

class Author():
    def __init__(self, name = '',paperIDs = []):
        self.__name = name
        self.__paperIDs = set(paperIDs)
        self.coAuthors = {} #dict with author names as key and number of times authors worked together as value

class Paper():
    def __init__(self, title = '', pageID = '', abstract = '', date = '', keywords = [], citedByIDs = [], authorNames = []):
        self.__title = title
        self.__pageID = pageID
        self.__abstract = abstract
        self.__date = date
        self.__keywords = keywords
        self.__citedByIDs = citedByIDs 
        self.__authorNames = authorNames 

        #these lists get arranged by importance based on networkx.pagerank
        self.__citedBy = []  #IDs
        self.__doesCite = [] #IDs
        self.__authors = []  #Objects
```

Currently I pickle the entire network by passing Network as the object:

```
def saveGraph(self,obj,filename):
    with open(filename,'w') as outf:
        pickle.dump(obj,outf)
```

Now the problem is the pickle file is becoming very large. It follows that saving and loading it take a very long time, additionally as it becomes too large, say 20gb, it will not be able to load into memory.

My first and most important problem is crawling for more data. I crawl by gathering the papers which cited each leaf, and by gathering the papers by each author. This method requires me to check if a paper already exists in the dict and if it does add a citation link, otherwise create a new paper. I also want to back up somewhat frequently while crawling but saving a pickle file so big takes too long.

Is there another way to store the data; a more efficient way to pickle my objects; perhaps a way to only update my database for all the changed files, rather than make a new pickle every time I save; and is it possible only to load a portion of the objects into my memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest writing a tool to pump your data into a graph database.

- Neo4j: http://www.neo4j.org/
- Titan: http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/

There is a language called Gremlin that allows you to do traversals and searches over the graph regardless of the storage technology.

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Gremlin-Query-Language

If you need a cheap server to practice on, I'd recommend firing up an instance in Amazon's EC2. You can start the server, do your work, then shut it down to keep costs down.